# Randomly assigning labels to elements in a 2 dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a 4x4 symmetrical 2 dimensional array with 0's on a long diagonal like this:

```
[0 1 2 3]
[1 0 3 4]
[2 3 0 5]
[3 4 5 0]
```

I want to randomly equally assign 2 labels to every column, in order to categorize these numbers into groups. For example, group 1 might contain the numbers from columns 1 and 3, and group 2 might contain the rest of the columns 2 and 4.

Using Python, how do I randomly equally (so that there are an equal amount of every label) assign n labels to columns in a mxm 2 dimensional symmetrical array?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this.  To start off with, if your matrix is 5x5, how do you get equal numbers of columns in every group?  I'm not clear on the desired outcome.  Do you call each group a list with columns in each list?  Or elements?

Comment: Also, please try something and show us even if it does not :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the concept of labelling columns works here. These are not columns but elements with the same index point in multiple lists. Why not create a LabelList and use that to access the 'columns' you want. You can randomly order the LabelList

```
import random
LabelList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
random.shuffle(LabelList)
print LabelList
```

Now you have a randomly ordered Label List, and you can use this in order to access your '4x4 Array' which is really a list of four lists in python terms. Now in each list within your array 'column1' is accessed by referencing LabelList[0] and so on. If you want to work in terms of pairs of columns the first two elements of the LabelList will refrence the index points in your lists that you are interested in pairing.

for example:

```
List = [[0, 1, 2, 3],[1, 0, 3, 4],[2, 3, 0, 5],[3, 4, 5, 0]]
for elem in List:
     print List[LabelList[0]]
```

will return the 'column' that is referenced by the first element in the LabelList which has been randomly shuffled into that point.

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but hope it helps.